# Reading the text using regular expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I want to extract all values from the text line below using regular expressions:

> (Sales (Type  0  0  **0  0  000  0  0 0  0**) "**Product**" "**ProductType**" "" "**0000**" "**0000**")                ;;ProductName 000

How to write regular expression for this? am using C#.

am using the following code to read the text file

```
 string expr = @"^\(Sales \(Type \d \d((?: \d+){7})\) "([^"]+)" "([^"]+)" "" "(\d+)" "(\d+)"
```

";
            Regex regex = new Regex(expr);

```
        using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(@"C:\records.log"))
        {

            while ((line = r.ReadLine()) != null)
            {


                foreach (Match m in regex.Matches(line))
                {
                   string value = m.Value.Trim();
                   MessageBox.Show(value);
                }
            }
        }
```

is it right? but i cant get the value

Comment: Please exactly list all the "values" you want to extract.

Comment: in Type from last 7 values and " Product" and "ProductType " and "0000" and "0000"

Comment: No. Make a precise list, in your question. Oh highlight them by adding underscores to the string or something. Everything else is vague.

Comment: Tomalak i added ** to the values which i want to get as a string..

Comment: Maybe you could give us a few input and the desired output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
^\(Sales \(Type \d \d((?: \d+){7})\) "([^"]+)" "([^"]+)" "" "(\d+)" "(\d+)"
```

matches these values in your sample string

- match group 1: `' 0 0 000 0 0 0 0'` (trim contents and split on space to get individual values)
- match group 2: `'Product'`
- match group 3: `'ProductType'`
- match group 4: `'0000'`
- match group 5: `'0000'`

You could also just split the entire string on space and pick the parts you want, entirely without regex. However, regular expressions make sure the string looks right, whereas a simple split does not.

Comment: @deep: You use `String.Split()` to split your values.

Comment: @ plz look my updated question, i just new to regex, am using the above code to read, but i cant get the values.??

Comment: @deep: Look at the numbered match groups.

Answer (score 1):

This could be useful, enter in the string you want the regular expression generated for and it will generate the RegEx in the selected language. 
http://txt2re.com/

Liam

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can split on `[( ";]+`, that is, one or more parenthesis, spaces, quotes or semicolons.